# Skip "You did not select a file to upload" error and display all other errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When I upload images, how do I ignore the "You did not select a file to upload" error and display all the other errors when an image is being upload?

```
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);

    if (!$upload) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
    } else {
        $images = $this->upload->data();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is when `$upload` fails because no files have been uploaded, run:

```
$images = $this->upload->data();
```

Or display the other image upload error. How can I do it?

Comment: That is not a good practice. If you still want to do that, just replace that error by str_replace() or regular expression. and then send the error message to the view.

And one more option is to change core library. but, it is very bad option.

There is no other option to do this with the codeigniter library file.

Why You want to do like this,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't -- there are no other errors nor data. If you look at the Upload library, you will see that the very first thing (understandably) it checks for is to see if there is a file. If there is no file, it sets the error and exits so nothing else gets processed:

```
// Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]))
{
    $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
    return FALSE;
}
```